# Securing large static files without hogging ASP.Net threads using IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, download, authorization, static-files

While my ASP.NET code is streaming a large file, is it tying down a thread completely? In other words, if 8 people are downloading large files and I only have 8 threads available, will no further requests be processed?

In any case, I need to find an alternative way of securing large static files, preferably by letting IIS serve it directly after the user has been authorized, in order to free the application server from having to deal with something that IIS, Nginx, etc can do better without hitting any managed code.

I believe Nginx allows this if your app puts the "X-Accel-Redirect" header in its response: http://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/.
Apache and Lighttpd have the same feature.

Any advice?

Comment: If the file is on disk, do a HttpResponse.Redirect(pathtofile, true);

Comment: Redirect won't work, as that'll require the browser to have direct access to the file. I'm looking for something more akin to a server-side url-rewrite than to a client-side redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the URL of the file is an appropriate solution.

You can prevent unauthorised users who have that URL from also downloading the file by using the standard authentication providers in asp.net.  If you turn `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` on (see http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules) the users authentication will be verified when they hit the URL, if they are authorised, they will be allowed to access the file.

In either case, downloading doesn't lock threads, just execution.  This is why the `maxConnections` settings has a default setting of `4294967295`. (see http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits)